# How to exclude read only fields using :input in jquery?

Tags: jquery, forms, readonly

thus far i've only been using some basic jquery selectors and functions.
but i'm looking at this [clear form function](http://www.learningjquery.com/2007/08/clearing-form-data) and i can't figure out how to add it so i can remove hidden inputs and readonly input from getting cleared.

can anybody help?
thanks.

```
function clearForm(form) {
  // iterate over all of the inputs for the form
  // element that was passed in
  $(':input', form).each(function() {
 var type = this.type;
 var tag = this.tagName.toLowerCase(); // normalize case
 // it's ok to reset the value attr of text inputs,
 // password inputs, and textareas
 if (type == 'text' || type == 'password' || tag == 'textarea')
   this.value = "";
 // checkboxes and radios need to have their checked state cleared
 // but should *not* have their 'value' changed
 else if (type == 'checkbox' || type == 'radio')
   this.checked = false;
 // select elements need to have their 'selectedIndex' property set to -1
 // (this works for both single and multiple select elements)
 else if (tag == 'select')
   this.selectedIndex = -1;
  });
};
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If the elements have a `readonly` attribute in their declaration, you can use [jQuery’s `:not()` selector](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/):

```
$(':input:not([readonly])', form)
```

Otherwise filter the read-only elements with something like this:

```
$(':input', form).each(function() {
    if (this.readOnly) return;
    // …
});
```

Comment: ya but how do you put that into the function?

Comment: sweet, that's exactly what i needed.

Answer (score 1):

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        try {
            var t = jQuery("input[type=text]").not("[readonly]").focus(function(){
                jQuery(this).blur();
            });
            alert(t.length);
        }
        catch(error){
            alert("error :" + error);
        }
    });
</script>
```